# kitchen-openstack ssl error while kitchen converging

Tags: test-kitchen

While trying to kitchen converge with kitchen-openstack receiving SSL errors as shown below, I have tried multiple ruby versions and in kitchen-openstack project it was mentioned that the error was fixed with ruby version 2.1.2 but even after using the latest version this issue still persists.

https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-openstack/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

```
v3.0.0.pre.1 (2016-02-12)

Full Changelog

Closed issues:

transport#username is not working for me #135
kitchen-openstack unable to retrieve network information #134
Password value in transport is not used in driver #133
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) #132
Volume: create new, attach existing, make from snapshot (seems not working) #131
Boot from Image (into new volume) #130
Put the yml files for each instance in .kitchen/kitchen-openstack #116
```

## Error Message:

```
[root@dev01 workspace]# kitchen converge
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.6.0)
-----> Creating <default-ubuntu-1404>...
>>>>>> Create failed on instance <default-ubuntu-1404>.
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/default-ubuntu-1404.log for more details
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read 
server hello A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
>>>>>> ----------------------
[root@dev01 workspace]#
```

Ruby Version installed and other gems:

```
[root@dev01 workspace]# ruby --version
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]
[root@dev01 workspace]# gem list | egrep 'berkshelf|kitchen|openssl'
berkshelf (4.3.1)
berkshelf-api-client (2.0.2)
kitchen-ec2 (1.0.0)
kitchen-openstack (3.0.0)
openssl (0.2.0)
ruby-hmac-openssl (0.1.0)
rubysl-openssl (2.8.0)
test-kitchen (1.6.0)
[root@dev01 workspace]#
```

Kitchen.yml file

```
[root@dev01 workspace]# cat .kitchen.yml

---
driver:
  name: openstack
  openstack_username: xxxxxxx
  openstack_api_key: xxxxxx # OpenStack Password
  openstack_auth_url: https://xxxxxxxx:5000/v2.0/tokens
  openstack_tenant: testing
  disable_ssl_validation: true
  require_chef_omnibus: true
  image_ref:  ova-ubuntu1404
  flavor_ref: m1.small
  network_ref: net1
  key_name: key_1
  private_key_path: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/key_1.pem
  public_key_path: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/key_1.pub
  security_groups:
  - ssh-in

transport:
  ssh_key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/key_1.pem
  username: ubuntu

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  http_proxy: http://proxy.aimsnew.com:80
  https_proxy: http://proxy.aimsnew.com:80

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[test01::default]
    attributes:
[root@dev01 workspace]#
```